# How to count string and sort them?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, count, heap

I am reading from an input file and want to read all letters and symbols. I am looking to create something bigger from this like encode it eventually - but I cannot seem to move from this block of trying to read in characters and use its frequency in a vector which I would sport in a heap. For context, how can I get something like this:

```
 "I am soo stuck."  --> i:1 a:1 m:1 s:2 o:2 t: 1 u:1 c: 1 k:1 :3 (represents spacing)
```

-- and how can i order them from least to greatest frequencies?
I tried maps, vectors, pairs -- everything - but no matter what i try nothing works

Comment: You first have to create a frequency map, then create another structure to sort by frequency.

Comment: Can you show the code you created in order to illustrate what problem you have exactly? I'm asking because what you show could just as well be someone's homework. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I've tried the freq map, but what structure to sort out? I tried using vector pair - but literally nothing seems to work. when attempting to sort it

Comment: I've added it Ultrich. Please forgive me as I am new here, and just in desperate need of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to first create a `std::map` for the frequencies (similar to your dictionary map, but you need to use a `std::(unordered)_map<char, int>` instead of `<int,char>`). Then you can use a `std::multimap` where you insert the all reverse pairs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

void print_frequencies(std::string text) {
    std::map<char, int> dictionary;
    for(auto c: text) {
        dictionary[c]++;
    }

    std::multimap<int, char> reverse;
    for ( auto [c, i] : dictionary ) {
        reverse.emplace(i, c);
    }

    for ( auto [i, c] : reverse ) {
        std::cout << c << ':' << i << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    print_frequencies("I am soo stuck.");
}
```

This works because `std::multimap` stores its elements in order of the key. You can play with it live on the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dK4q79j1f) compiler explorer.

If you only happen to have a pre C++17 compiler you cannot use structured bindings and need to use old school `std::pair` members. For example the second loop would look like this in C++14:

```
for ( auto e : dictionary ) {
    reverse.emplace(e.second, e.first);
}
```

Comment: This! This is basically it! Wow, thank you!! However, I have a few questions. I was thinking of a similar approach but one where I use a multiset instead. Would that have been efficient - and also, I am running into this error: "error: structured bindings only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’ [-Werror]". I managed to fix the error with running with a different compiler, but is there another way to write auto[c, I] to mean the same thing? I am not familiar with it

Comment: @ArianiP.: Add those flags to compiler unless you are stuck to C++11 or C++14.

Comment: @ArianiP. `std::set` and `std::multiset` are just as efficient as their map counterparts. You could as well use a set of pairs but you probably need to specify a custom comparison operation then.

Comment: @ArianiP. the structured bindings are those [`auto [i,c]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) constructs. This saves you the explicit call to `first` and `second` in the iteration. I will edit my answer to include pre C++17 code

Comment: What do you mean by special way?

Comment: I tried printing it with for(auto c: reverse)
    {
        cout << c.second << " : " << c.first;

    }. --but it does not print correctly, so I was wondering if there was a specific way or printing the output? @JakobStark